# Javascript: Checking equality of the functions themselves, not return values

Tags: javascript, function

I want to pass a function into another as a property. I then want to test whether that function is equal to a particular function:

```
function f(func) {
    if (func === testFunc) {
        console.log("They're the same!")
    }
}

function testFunc(x) {
   return x+1
}

f(testFunc)
```

The above works as expected. The conditional in the top function passes and the line is outputted to the console. However, if I pass the function with a property of its own, it is found not to be equal:

```
f(testFunc(2))
```

I assume this is because the return value is different. So how do I test whether the actual functions are the same, not their returning values? Is there a way?

Comment: Have you tried typeof?

Comment: Do you want to test the functions *contents* ? I.e.: the *code* ?

Comment: `testFunc` passes the function, `testFunc(2)` ***executes*** the function and passes the return value...

Comment: @MarcoS I think so thats what he wants.

Comment: `testFunc` will never be equals to `3`

Comment: Of course. I've got this all wrong. The top function is receiving the return value not the function. Need to rethink.

Comment: @user3574603: I can't think of a single use case for your question... :-( Please tell me why you need to run-time check if functions contents is the same... Sorry, I'm just curious... :-)

Comment: If you want to check for content, then you need to use uneval

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check, if 2 object's content are the same, then you need to use the uneval function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/uneval

Keep in mind this is worse than eval, so try to avoid it if possible.

Comment: @deceze That's why it's worse than eval, at least eval is supported by some other browsers.